# Facebook "Instagram-Style" Take Photo Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-feed

I've just noticed this following , relatively new thing on Facebook, when you upload a photo to Facebook, it shows it as the following with the text "Name took a Photo with Instagram", plus the "View on Instagram" link at the bottom. Is that something new ? I couldn't find any reference of this, but maybe I wasn't looking good enough :)

[image: Facebook Instagram action]

Thanks in advance for any assistance :D

Comment: Facebook will often create private APIs for companies (such as the one for The Gifts Project). It's probably something like that.

Comment: I also thought so , but I know there's this new Action API in the Timeline, so i thought it might be related to that somehow

Comment: @Johnny, this is using completely open APIs. Nothing custom here.

Comment: @Jeff, are you sure? I doubt the "View on Instagram" is part of FB's API.

Comment: I'm positive. Any app attributed large photo using the user generated photo capability (part of open graph) gets the attribution and link.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I've searched the web for how to make that "view on instagram" link, but can't find it. Mind explaining how to get it? Cheers!

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/action-links/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open graph enabled application where the action is "took" and the object is "photo". You can create your own open graph application using your own custom actions and objects. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Thanks man, Didn't test it but it seems workable :) If you have some demo code I can read up (preferably PHP that'd be best). Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 9):

To get the nice big photos, you'll need to mark them as user-generated.

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for, You definitely deserve the bounty :) Thanks!